# How to insert line feed in MYSQL result

Tags: mysql

How do you make this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRST_NAME,' ' ,LAST_NAME, ADDRESS1, CITY,', ',STATE, ZIP) AS NAME
```

Give a result like this:

```
Joe Donuts
123 Main St
New York, NY 11111
```

I tried adding '\n' to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you [edit] the question to add some information like if you are processing this just in MySQL, or if it passes out to some other platform? With the given information this appears like it might be an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CONCAT_WS` with `\n` as a newline separator:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS('\n', CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME),
              ADDRESS1,
              CONCAT(CITY, ', ', STATE, ' ', ZIP)) AS NAME
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: How are you viewing the results. In Workbench it does not format the lien feeds.

Comment: @PMH Then Workbench isn't showing the line breaks.  If you copy that output into something like Notepad++ or SublimeText, you should see the output I have in my answer (and your question).